# How can I save my initial page's url as a variable in js and use it after form submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```js
const currURL= window.location.href;
```

The above code is what I use to get the url of the current page, however, I thought I save this "currURL" as a constance so that it will not change value after I submit my form, apparently I'm wrong.

what I want to do is to use this button to invoke the js "clearFunction()",which will take me back to the initial page.

```html
<div>
   <button type="button" onclick="clearFunction()" class="button">Clear</button>
</div>
```

This is what I did:

```js
function clearFunction(){
  window.open(currURL,"_self");
}
```

but it's not working as the currURL will always change to the url of the page after I submit my form.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: window.history.back();

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies in javascript to save the value of current url and use it when ever you want to.

```
  function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Read the following page:- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: how can I get (cname, cvalue, exdays) these values?

Comment: DawnZHANG, I have updated my answer. It is an example code read, creating cookies in javascript. You can edit it according to your need.